# Scrollable years in dijit.form.DateTextBox

Tags: textbox, calendar, dojo

The dojox.widget.Calendar lets us scroll over the years easily. Can that be simulated/added to the DateTextBox widget?

I prefer the DateTextBox because of the validations and constraints it provides. Also, once opened, the Calendar widget (as in the livedocs site) cannot be closed till a date is selected. Whereas, the popup calendar in the DateTextBox does not have this problem.

The need is this: for a Date of Birth field, we cannot assume one random default year as, let's say, the potential users might be born any time between 1960 to 2000. So, the user might have to do multiple clicks (the older he is, the more number of clicks?!!). How can this usability problem be addressed? The Calendar widget helps in easy navigation. But the DateTextBox shows only 3 years at a time.

Can this be done with any CSS change? Any possible mix and match of components?

I am using v1.7.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same need. There is an open ticket ([10002](http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10002)) but nothing has been done for years. I will try to get an answer on the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks! Hope this is addressed soon (wonder why? seems to be a usability concern.)